# How does one stop Android from tilting ones layout?

Tags: android, layout

how would one stop Android from tilting ones layout? I created a nice vertical layout and want ot to sray vertical even when the device is horizontal. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: this is the 1000000th question like this in this site.

Comment: Note that this will not work well for devices that cannot be turned portrait, such as Google TV.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your Activity in your Manifest File

```
 <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       >
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the following line of code: 
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     ...
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
     ...
}
```